Google Cloud vertex Ai PERMISSION_DENIED when accessing project
I have spent many hours trying to track down the solution to a problem with sending a (JWT/OAuth2 authorised) query (with PHP/cURL) to what I think is a GC endpoint model (see below). I keep getting the response below. I think the relevant permissions are in place... Can anyone help please?
Many thanks in advance...
Input:
URL = https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/XXXXX/locations/us-central1/endpoints/gemini-1.5-flash-001:predict
(XXXXX = the actual project id as required).

Payload:
$instance = [
    'image' => ['bytes' => $b64_filedata], // This encoded correctly from image file..
    'parameters' => [
        'confidenceThreshold' => 0.5,
        'maxResults' => 5,
    ]
];

Required response: A json-formatted text description of the image.
Actual Response:
[error] => stdClass Object
        (
            [code] => 403
            [message] => Permission 'aiplatform.endpoints.predict' denied on resource '//aiplatform.googleapis.com/projects/XXXXX/locations/us-central1/endpoints/gemini-1.5-flash-001' (or it may not exist).
            [status] => PERMISSION_DENIED
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [@type] => type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo
                            [reason] => IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED
                            [domain] => aiplatform.googleapis.com
                            [metadata] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [permission] => aiplatform.endpoints.predict
                                    [resource] => projects/XXXXX/locations/us-central1/endpoints/gemini-1.5-flash-001
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)


From where are you requesting the endpoint? Which permission are granted to the used identity?

In order to use vertex you need to authenticate it to Google cloud. as everything in vertex is run via your Google Cloud console.
You may want to check this page: Authenticate to Vertex AI 
I normally use the CLI

gcloud auth application-default login

When you do it you need to pick a project to run from. If you pick the wrong one you will get PERMISSION_DENIED as it doesn't have access to the project projects/XXXXX/

LInda, Many thanks for your answer - I'll check this out...

I got the same error, I can set google vertex to access Gemini models properly, I use my service account and assigned Vertex AI Administrator, which is contains permission "aiplatform.endpoints.predict", but I got this error when I try model "meta/llama3-405b-instruct-maas" and this URL "https://us-east1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/my-projectId/locations/us-east1/endpoints/openapi/chat/completions"
What is the issue? I still able to call Gemini API with no issue.
Any answer will be very appreciated as it is blocked my task.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
